# Pass EditText's value to another activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I made a Tic-tac-toe game, I currently have 3 activities. I want to pass edit text string values to another activity for later to use as names.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Input Player Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Input Player 2 Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

I have two edit texts for two names and I want to pass those names as strings to another activity to use them as names.

```
if (firstPlayer.contains(1) && firstPlayer.contains(2) && firstPlayer.contains(3)) {
    winnerPlayer = 1
    score++
    scoreText.text = "Player 1: $score"
}

if (secondPlayer.contains(1) && secondPlayer.contains(2) && secondPlayer.contains(3)) {
    winnerPlayer = 2
    score2++
    scoreText2.text = "Player 2: $score2"
}
```

as you can see I have manually inputted `Player 1` and `Player 2`. I'm trying to replace them with name1 and name2 which are strings that have been inputted before. I wrote some code with intent but could get it to work. App just crashed and crashed.

Comment: Using intent is the right path. Show us the code that you tried and the crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
String string1 = editTextName.getText();
String string2 = editTextName2.getText();
intent.putExtra("string1", string1);
intent.putExtra("string2", string2);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it in the AnotherActivity.class like below

```
String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("string1");
String string2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("string2");
```